# Write pcap file about TCP traffic of a web-crawler

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler, scapy, pcap

url request and sniff(count=x) don't work together. sniff(count) is waiting for x packets to sniff, and though I have to put the line before the url-request it blocks the program, the url-request never starts and it never sniffs any packet.

When I opened 2 Windows in ubuntu command line, it worked. In the first window I activated the interactive mode of python and activated the sniffer. After doing that, I started the web-crawler int the second window and the sniffer in the 1st window received the packets correctly and put it on the screen / into a pcap-file.

Now the easiest way would be to write 2 scripts and start them from 2 different Windows, but I want to do the complete work in one script: Webcrawling, sniffing the packets and putting them into a pcap-file

Here is the code that does not work:

```
class spider():
…
    def parse():
        a = sniff(filter="icmp and host 128.65.210.181", count=1)
        req = urllib.request.urlopen(self.next_url.replace(" ",""))
        a.nsummary()
        charset = req.info().get_content_charset()
```

Now the first line blocks the program, waiting 4 the packet to come in, what cannot do so because only in the next line the request is done. Swapping the lines also doesn't work. I think that the only way to resolve the problem is to work with paralessisms, so I've also tried this:

```
class protocoller(): 
    ...
    def run(self):
         self.pkt = sniff(count=5) # and here it blocks
…
prot = protocoller()
Main.thr = threading.Thread(target=prot.run())
Main.thr.start()
```

I Always thought that the thread is running indipendently from the main program, but it blocks it as if it would be part of it. Any suggestions?

So what I would need is a solution in which the web-crawler and the IP/TCP protocoller based on scapy are running independently from each other.

Could the sr()-function of scapy be an alternative?

```
https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html
```

Is it possible to put the request manually in the packet and to put the received packet into the pcap-file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't show what's going on in other threads so I assume you've got a second thread to do the request etc. If all that is in order the obvious error is here:

```
Main.thr = threading.Thread(target=prot.run())
```

This executes the function `prot.run` and passes the result to the `target` parameter of `Thread`. It should be:

```
Main.thr = threading.Thread(target=prot.run)
```

This passes the function itself into `Thread`

Comment: I've just created 1 additional thread. run() is a method of the class protocoller and so of the object prot. The class of the first part is called spider() and its method is parse().

Answer (score 2):

The other answer works great.
FYI, Scapy 2.4.3 also has a native way of doing this:

https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#asynchronous-sniffing

Comment: ..and I will try it out later.